# RTSP implementation for iOS Application

Tags: ios, rtsp

I have tried almost all cocoapods available for RTSP.
VLC is the best one but it does not complete my purpose. chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS does not work too.
Can anyone guide me which library can be used for the same?

Answer (score 0):

JW player plays your video.Check the following library.it is a help.
https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-ios-demo

Comment: The introduction specifies RTMP streaming support. Are you sure about RTSP streaming support?